# mysql to mariadb migration

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We are using mysql 5.5.16 in production servers. Now we are planning either mysql upgrade(5.6/5.7) or migration to mariadb latest version.Please suggest which option is best.

If mariadb option is best then Please let me know the steps for migrating  mysql 5.5.16 to mariadb latest version ?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-features/

Comment: What are your constraints?  Can you afford enough downtime to dump and reload the data?  Can you set up replication and move to a new machine at the same time?  Will you be doing Galera clustering as part of the upgrade?