# Mysql 5.5 migration to mariadb 10.1.12

Tags: mariadb

Please let me know is it possible to migrate mysql 5.5 to maradb 10.1.12 directly?
If it is not possible then kindly let me know the steps for migration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql to mariadb migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051896/mysql-to-mariadb-migration)

Comment: Voting to close because of how similar this is to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051896/mysql-to-mariadb-migration .  Suggest you consolidate comments/questions in that thread.